# Processing AD user certificates

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, pki

I'm quite a noob in Powershell, and the actual issue is that I'm a bit lost on how to search through various properties and having a hard time finding examples that match my needs.

With this said, what I need is to search through Active Directory to find user S/MIME certificates that are about to be expired, issued from specific Certification Authority.

What I have already:

```
$Mail = user@example.com
$allProfileCerts = Get-ADUser -Server example.com:3268 -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} -Properties Certificates  | select Certificates
```

The result is:

```
       Handle Issuer     Subject                                                                                                             
       ------ ------     -------                                                                                                             
1625625266096 CN=<CA1>   E=test.user@example.com, CN=Test User, OU=Normal, OU=Users, OU=EXAMPLE, ...
1625625265968 CN=<CA2>   E=test.user@example.com, CN=Test User, O=Example Company, ...    
1625625271728 CN=<CA1>   CN=Test User, OU=Normal, OU=Users, OU=EXAMPLE, ...
```

I figured that the next step can be:

```
$allProfileCerts.Certificates | foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_}
```

The results provide more details (redacted to remove PII):

```
EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)}
DnsNameList              : {Test User}
SendAsTrustedIssuer      : False
EnrollmentPolicyEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
EnrollmentServerEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
PolicyId                 : 
Archived                 : False
Extensions               : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
FriendlyName             : 
IssuerName               : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter                 : 29/05/2021 10:47:00
NotBefore                : 11/12/2018 09:47:00
HasPrivateKey            : False
PrivateKey               : 
PublicKey                : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData                  : {48, 130, 8, 51...}
SerialNumber             : <snip>
SubjectName              : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm       : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint               : <snip>
Version                  : 3
Handle                   : 1625625266096
Issuer                   : <ISSUER1>
Subject                  : <subject>

EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)}
DnsNameList              : {Test User}
SendAsTrustedIssuer      : False
EnrollmentPolicyEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
EnrollmentServerEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
PolicyId                 : 
Archived                 : False
Extensions               : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
FriendlyName             : 
IssuerName               : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter                 : 30/08/2020 14:00:00
NotBefore                : 30/08/2018 02:00:00
HasPrivateKey            : False
PrivateKey               : 
PublicKey                : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData                  : {48, 130, 5, 127...}
SerialNumber             : <snip>
SubjectName              : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm       : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint               : <snip>
Version                  : 3
Handle                   : 1625625265968
Issuer                   : <ISSUER2>
Subject                  : <subject>

EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Encrypting File System (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4)}
DnsNameList              : {Test User}
SendAsTrustedIssuer      : False
EnrollmentPolicyEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
EnrollmentServerEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
PolicyId                 : 
Archived                 : False
Extensions               : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
FriendlyName             : 
IssuerName               : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter                 : 09/04/2020 15:57:37
NotBefore                : 22/10/2017 15:57:37
HasPrivateKey            : False
PrivateKey               : 
PublicKey                : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData                  : {48, 130, 8, 4...}
SerialNumber             : <snip>
SubjectName              : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm       : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint               : <snip>
Version                  : 3
Handle                   : 1625625271728
Issuer                   : <ISSUER1>
Subject                  : <subject>
```

I also figured that I can easily filter by date using `Where-Object NotAfter...` (correct me if I'm wrong on this :) ), but for love of the world I can't figure how to filter for `EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)}`. I think it's an array (there might be more than one EKU in any given cert), but how can I filter by array elements?

Bonus question: if I have:

```
$oneCert = $allProfileCerts.Certificates | foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_} | Where-Object SerialNumber -Match "<SN>"
```

How do I then access "NotAfter" field? I tried `$oneCert."NotAfter"`, `$oneCert["NotAfter"]`, `$oneCert | % NotAfter`, `$oneCert | select -expandproperty "NotAfter"` - neither is working :/

EDIT: code that works, based on @tomalak proposal:

```
Get-ADUser -Server $Server -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} -Property Certificates |
    ForEach-Object {
        # ...we have "user" objects here
        Write-Host $_

        $_.Certificates | 
            foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_} |
            Where-Object {
                $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq "Secure Email"
            }
    } |
    ForEach-Object {
    # ...we have "certificate" objects here
    Write-Host $_.Issuer
}
```

Comment: Have you tried referencing `$oneCert.EnhancedKeyUsageList`? PowerShell adds a `ScriptProperty` to the type data for `X509Certificate2`, so you don't have to parse it out manually

Comment: Thank you all for useful answers, turns out what I described above is not exactly what I did in my tests :/ I have added | fl -f * to see all properties, and I just now realized that it returns a string, not an object I can manipulate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use `Where-Object` to filter the pipeline, and `-eq` to filter lists. In this case, something like:

```
$adUser.Certificates | Where-Object {
    $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.oid.Value -eq "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4"
}
```

would give you all the user's certificates that have `"1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4"` in their EKU list.

Note that when Powershell (4.0 and up) sees such an expression `$object.Property.ChildProperty.SomeData`, it fetches *all* `Property` values, for all of them it fetches *all* `ChildProperty` values, and for all of *them* it fetches all `SomeData` values. This saves quite some typing. In a traditional imperative language you'd need nested loops for that, in Powershell you don't need any loops at all.

Knowing this, `$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.oid.Value -eq "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4"` becomes possible, because `-eq` is not your traditional "equality" operator: It takes a list of values and filters them down, i.e.:

```
1,2,3 -eq 3  # produces 3
1,3,3 -eq 3  # produces 3,3
```

You could go as far as

```
Get-ADUser -Property Certificates | Where-Object {
    $_.Certificates.EnhancedKeyUsageList.oid.Value -eq "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4"
}
```

to get all AD users that have a matching certificate in one go.

Since you want to filter two properties per certificate, I would recommend some variation of

```
$minValid = (Get-Date).AddMonths(6)

Get-ADUser -Property Certificates -PipelineVariable user | ForEach-Object {
    # ...we have "user" objects here
    Write-Host $_

    $_.Certificates | Where-Object {
        $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.oid.Value -eq "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4" -and $_.NotAfter -lt $minValid
    }
} | ForEach-Object {
    # ...we have "certificate" objects here
    Write-Host $_
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, this helped a lot! For the record, AD provides X509Certificate object, which you need to cast to X509Certificate2 for any filters to work. Also, the filter should look like this: { $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq "Secure Email" }.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm sure filtering by OID is possible as well, but filtering by name is a lot less bulky of course.

Comment: Both oid and name are fine, afaik, but it's "ObjectID", not "OID", and "objectid.value" doesn't work - "objectid" does. Just minor clarifications if anyone reads that later :-)

Comment: Okay :) I could not test this properly because I could not find any certificate on my system that had something in its `EnhancedKeyUsageList`, I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I would filter on the `ObjectId` value:

```
$certificates |Where-Object {$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.ObjectId -like '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2'}
```

This example relies on Property Enumeration of the OIDs in `EnhancedKeyUsageList` so it will only work in PowerShell 4.0 or newer